# How to access the nativeElement of a Component in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I have two components and one with attribute selector. The child component is,

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: '[app-bar-chart]',
    templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.css']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() chartContainer: ElementRef;
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() chartData: {
        title: string,
        content: {
            label: string,
            value: number,
            fill?: string
        }[]
    }[];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.chartContainer);
        console.log(this.chartContainer.nativeElement);
    }

}
```

The parent component is,

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Output, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    template: `<div><div class="graph-image" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" app-bar-chart [title]="barChartTitle" [chartData]="ChartData" [chartContainer]="chartContainer" #chartContainer></div></div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    barChartTitle = 'Transaction History';
    ChartData = [
        {
            "title": "May2017",
            "content": [
                {
                    "label": "payable",
                    "value": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Jun2017",
            "content": [
                {
                    "label": "payable",
                    "value": 120
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

I am passing the local reference from the parent component to the child component. When I am consoling the native element of this local reference it is 'undefined'. How can I access the native element so that I can access the style width and height of the component div.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem is that if you define a template reference on the element that Angular views as a host element of the component, you will get a reference to the component instance. Here:

```
<... chartContainer]="chartContainer" #chartContainer></div>
```

`chartContainer` will point to the instance of the `BarChartComponent` and that is why `nativeElement` is undefined.

To get `elementRef` of the host element, you don't need any bindings or lifecycle hooks, just inject the element into the constructor:

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(element: ElementRef) {
        console.log(element.nativeElement);
   }
```

Comment: In the case where a parent waits for its childdren ngAfterViewInit is correct. However, when the child receives the parent ngOnInit should be ok. Is it ok?

Comment: @kimy82, I misunderstood the question. I updated the answer

Comment: This was particularly helpful as it allowed me to access both the component instance and the native `ElementRef` from a single `@ViewChildren` query.

Answer (score 84):

If you need the `ElementRef` of a component, you can't use a template variable. If the element is a component, you'll get the component instance instead. A template variable only returns `ElementRef` for plain HTML elements.

To get `ElementRef` of a component, you need to use `@ViewChild()`

```ts
@ViewChild('chartContainer', { read: ElementRef }) myChartContainer:ElementRef;
```

and then pass it along with

```ts
[chartContainer]="myChartContainer"
```

I would make the input a setter

```ts
 private _chartContainer:ElementRef;
 @Input() 
 set chartContainer(value: ElementRef) {
   this._chartContainer = value;
   console.log(this.chartContainer);
   console.log(this.chartContainer.nativeElement);
 }
```

but `ngOnInit` works as well [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VqUDO2KQnTaPjqBtve3i?p=preview)

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Let's say it's not the first time I applied f(x) with (arguably) the same x and got y1 and y2 where y1 != y2 too many times .. ^^ Grüße aus Graz.

Comment: Shouldn't (ElementRef value) be (value: ElementRef)?

Comment: @reika thanks for the hint. You are right. I mixed it up with Dart a bit ;-)

Comment: It works like a charm by using {read: ElementRef}. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

As others said, you get the Component's reference when you try to reference it with the `@ViewChild('templateId') element;` property. But that's totally fine, because we can reference the nativeElement of the child component in its constructor and make it publicly available from the outside components:

```js
  // Child component
  nativeElement: HTMLElement;

  constructor(element: ElementRef) {
    this.nativeElement = element.nativeElement;
  }
```

```js
  // Parent component:
 
  @ViewChild('childId') element; // element.nativeElement works now
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first selector you have set  *'[app-bar-chart]'* and it should be without square brachets.
To pass the parent you should use:

```
 [chartContainer]="this"
```

instead of:

```
 [chartContainer]="chartContainer"
```