# In Angular 2, how can I focus to the bottom of a div on button click

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a div with lot of components. On button click, the focus should reach to the bottom of the div. How is it possible in Angular 2?

Comment: have you tried getting the page to scroll? i recall there being a scrollTo() method

Comment: Could you please provide the sample code?

Comment: try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView or see the acepted answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use viewchild and nativeelement. Then you will get an element, and you will able to use .focus() method. follow viewchild and nativeelement.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45344187/4834833
It will help you.